# PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, phantomjs, google-chrome-headless

I have used "MVC ASP.NET Core with Angular" template.
I am trying to include phantomJS and run the tests, but i get the following errors:

```
    ERROR in [at-loader] ..\\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js.d.ts:122:11 TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone'. 

ERROR in [at-loader] ..\\node_modules\zone.js\ dist\zone.js.d.ts:363:14 TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HasTaskState'. 

ERROR in [at-loader] ..\\node_modules\zone.js\ dist\zone.js.d.ts:372:14 TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TaskType'. 

ERROR in [at-loader] ..\\node_modules\zone.js\ dist\zone.js.d.ts:458:15 TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone'.

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map at ../wwwroot/dist/vendor.js:12460
```

Below are the node module version i have been using(package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.2",
    "@types/node": "7.0.18",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.5",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.29",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.3.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "3.5.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.15"
  }`
```

and the tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
        "types": [ "node" ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "bin",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}`
```

and the webpack.config.js code is :

```
`const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
            modules: [path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")]
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = '..//wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': '..//ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('..//wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });
    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
`
```

How can i solve the errors mentioned above? I have tried solutions mentioned in https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript/issues/83. Nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Looking forward for some answer.

Thanks.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~``
Solution to include chrome headless:

included "puppeteer" in package.json under dev dependencies.

Configured in Karma.config.js:

```
    const ChromiumRevision = require('puppeteer/package.json').puppeteer.chromium_revision;
const Downloader = require('puppeteer/utils/ChromiumDownloader');
const revisionInfo = Downloader.revisionInfo(Downloader.currentPlatform(), ChromiumRevision);


module.exports = function (config) {

     config.set({ ...

         browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    ..
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> phantomJS and run the tests, but i get the following errors:

PhantomJS is old and doesn't support ES6 features like `Map`. You can try to get it to work with `core-js` but you are essentially trying to lift a dead tech to modern standards.

## More

The replacement for phantomjs is chrome headless.

Comment: Can you please share an example for chrome headless? Will this chrome headless work in build environments like VSTS?

Comment: I used `"puppeteer": "^0.11.0"` and configured in karma.config.js. Code is added above.